# Using Spring's @RequestBody and reading HttpServletRequest.getInputStream() afterwards

Tags: json, spring, http, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm mapping my request's JSON POST data into an object using Spring's `@RequestBody` annotation and `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`. However after that I'd like to read the data in `String` form to do some additional authentication. But when the marshalling has happened, the `InputStream` in `HttpServletRequest` is empty. Once I remove the `@RequestBody` parameter from the method the reading of POST data into a `String` works as expected.

Do I have to compromise by giving up the `@RequestBody` and doing the binding somehow manually or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need to read for your additional authentication?

Comment: I need the request body as `String`, which concatenated with a secret, forms a token, from which I calculate SHA-1 hash, which is then compared to a hash in the headers. The result of this comparison is then used to decide whether or not I should store the object mapped by the `@RequestBody` process.

Comment: Can't you read that token from the @RequestBody parameter?

Comment: No, since that'd require parsing it back to JSON format and there's a high possibility that it wouldn't be equal to the original form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically you need to compute a hash of the request body. The elegant way to do it is to apply a decorator to the `InputStream`.

For example, inside a handler method (in this case you can't use `@RequestBody` and need to create `HttpMessageConverter` manually):

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    final HashingInputStreamDecorator d = 
        new HashingInputStreamDecorator(request.getInputStream(), secretKey);
    HttpServletRequest wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return d;
        }
    };

    HttpMessageConverter conv = ...;
    Foo requestBody = (Foo) conv.read(Foo.class, new ServletServerHttpRequest(wrapper));
    String hash = d.getHash();

    ...
}
```

where hash is computed incrementally in overriden `read` methods of `HashingInputStreamDecorator`.

You can also use `@RequestBody` if you create a `Filter` to apply the decorator. In this case decorator can pass the computed hash to the handler method as a request attribute. However, you need to map this filter carefully to apply it only to the requests to specific handler method.

Comment: What do you mean by `Filter`? `web.xml` filters? I wonder if I could use Spring Security filters for this kind of thing...

Comment: @hleinone: Yes, I meant `web.xml` filter. Although you can configure it via Spring Security filter chain, but in this case you will need to handle its url pattern manually, since Spring Security doesn't provide selective filter chains (actually it does, but that feature is overcomplicated).

Comment: You mean something like this: `<sec:filter-chain pattern="/api/private/**" filters="requestAuthenticationFilter" />`? This would be pretty elegant solution, though I wonder if the request data is then still available in the `MessageConverter`.

Comment: @hleinone: Yes, I mean this solution. Request data will be available if hashing functionality is applied to the input stream as a decorator.

Comment: I ended up creating a Spring Security filter with the decoration done pretty much the same manner than in `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

In your urlMapping bean you can declare list of additional interceptors:

```
  <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.foo.MyAuthInterceptor"/>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Those interceptors have access to HttpServletRequest, though if you read from the stream the chances are that parameter mapper won't be able to read it.

```
public class AuthInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    ...
  }

  public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView mav) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume this configuration authenticates all the requests in the application. My requirement is to only do that only for certain paths.

Comment: You can check the path inside preHandle() implementation.

Comment: Or create a separate `HandlerMapping` with the authenticated paths specified in its `mappings` property.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, one common way used with JAX-RS (which is somewhat similar to Spring MVC with respect to binding requests) is to first "bind" into some intermediate raw type (usually byte[], but String also works), and manually bind from that to object, using underlying data binder (Jackson). I often do this to be able to fully customize error handling of data binding.

Comment: I guess this would be the best solution if complete customization case-by-case was required. For my case the filter solution in axtavt's answer works better, since it's completely transparent on the Spring controller level.