# How to get HttpRequest getEntity data in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

```
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> mParams;
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

mParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testKey", "John"));
mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testSerial", "003-100"));
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/test/getRequiredEnv");

request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mParams, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

// TestController.java

```
@RestController
public class TestController {   

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/getRequiredEnv", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseInfo getRequiredEnv(
                @RequestParam("testKey") String testKey, 
                @RequestParam("testValue") String testValue, 
                @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {

    logger.info("Test Key [" + testKey + "]");
    logger.info("Test Value [" + testValue + "]");

    return new TestResponseInfo("0001", "ABC");
}
```

Can someone please tell me is this the correct way to get data from 'Request.setEntity' in SpringMVC rest controller or I am missing something?

Secondly, in postman "httpPost" request I pass the parameters (testKey & testValue) as headers or as body?

Thirdly, without knowing the parameters in httpPost request can I able to parse the incoming request and extract the parameters from it in Spring controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it would be good to know the content-type of the request that is sent.

So I guess you want to get the body of the request. To get all request parameters if you don't know the parameter names beforehand you can use `@RequestParam` with type `Map<String, String>` to get all params:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getRequiredEnv", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseInfo getRequiredEnv(
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> allParams,
            @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers)
```

But I am not sure if this works because it also depends on the content-type. E.g. for form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) have a look at the Spring documentation about [@RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) which states about one of the default message converters `FormHttpMessageConverter`:

> FormHttpMessageConverter converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap.

So try:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getRequiredEnv", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseInfo getRequiredEnv(
            @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String>,
            @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers)
```

Alternatively there is also `HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()` which gets you a Map. You can get the request by just including `HttpServletRequest request` as a method argument.

If you know the paramters beforehand, annotating your POJO that resembles the form data with `@ModelAttribute` should also work like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getRequiredEnv", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseInfo getRequiredEnv(
        @@ModelAttribute Test myTestPojo,
        @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers)
```

Or you could also send data as application/json and when including jackson as a dependency, `@Requestbody` will map your data to a POJO. Have a look at e.g. [Spring JSON request body not mapped to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960117/spring-json-request-body-not-mapped-to-java-pojo).

In regard to your second question httpPost will pass the parameters as body since it is a POST request.

Comment: Thanks @dudel for the detail elaboration. Can you tell me is there any way to simply print RAW request/data sent from client without knowing parameters or any other stuff?

Comment: In that case you can use either use `getInputStream()` or `getReader()` from the `HttpServletRequest`, but please note that you can only read it once.

Comment: Perfect. Can we read the request/data later on as described in below link?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457963/spring-rest-service-retrieving-json-from-request

Comment: Hmm, you mean to use @RequestBody and still have the data from the inputstream? That will get more complicated, but could work with a ServletFilter as described in the link. Also this answer may help you, although it is for a different purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4097709/1496158